# AngularJs Assign Json value to multiple scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have two form in one page one for reference of previous data and one is a actual form. So i have to assign same json(which actually are come from  database) to two different form in a page. I have a problem when I change the option value in main form the reference form value also change. What I want is even the main form change value, reference form should retain old value. please check my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/sanuman/kts7je89/24/
thank you for your any help and suggestions.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.muni=[
    {
        "id": 24001,
        "VDC_Muni_Code": "24001",
        "VDC_Muni_Name_Eng": "Anaikot",
        "tbl_district_id": 24
    },
    {
        "id": 24002,
        "VDC_Muni_Code": "24002",
        "VDC_Muni_Name_Eng": "Baldthali",
        "tbl_district_id": 24
    },
    {
        "id": 24003,
        "VDC_Muni_Code": "24003",
        "VDC_Muni_Name_Eng": "Balting",
        "tbl_district_id": 24
    },
    {
        "id": 24004,
        "VDC_Muni_Code": "24004",
        "VDC_Muni_Name_Eng": "Baluwapati",
        "tbl_district_id": 24
    }
   ];
    $scope.service_data=[
    {
        "tbl_vdc_municipality_id": 24001
    },
    {
        "tbl_vdc_municipality_id": 24004
    },
    {
        "tbl_vdc_municipality_id": 24002
    },
    {
        "tbl_vdc_municipality_id": 24003
    }

];
    $scope.municipalities_ref = $scope.muni;
    $scope.municipalities = $scope.muni;
 $scope.wspVdcMuniTbls = $scope.service_data;
 $scope.wspVdcMuniTblsRef = $scope.service_data;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h2>
  Main Form
  </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="wspVdcMuniTblRef in wspVdcMuniTblsRef">
 <select 
      ng-model="wspVdcMuniTblRef.tbl_vdc_municipality_id" 
   options="municipalities_ref"
   ng-options="municipality_ref.id as municipality_ref.VDC_Muni_Name_Eng for municipality_ref in municipalities_ref">
 </select>
  </div>

<h2>
Reference Form
</h2>
  
  <div ng-repeat="wspVdcMuniTbl in wspVdcMuniTbls">
 <select 
  ng-model="wspVdcMuniTbl.tbl_vdc_municipality_id" 
     options="municipalities"
  ng-options="municipality.id as municipality.VDC_Muni_Name_Eng for municipality in municipalities">
 </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've provided work as expected. The thing is that both `$scope.municipalities` and `$scope.municipalities_ref` points to the same object (same for `$scope.wspVdcMuniTbls` and `$scope.wspVdcMuniTblsRef`) when this assigment is made:

```
$scope.municipalities = $scope.muni;
$scope.municipalities_ref = $scope.muni;
$scope.wspVdcMuniTbls = $scope.service_data;
$scope.wspVdcMuniTblsRef = $scope.service_data;
```

You should create a copy of `$scope.muni` and `$scope.service_data` like this:

```
$scope.municipalities_ref = angular.copy($scope.muni);
$scope.wspVdcMuniTblsRef = angular.copy($scope.service_data);
```

The documentation of `angular.copy(source, [destination]);` can be find [there](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).